# How can I make carrierwave not save the original file after versions are processed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, carrierwave

I'm using CarrierWave for my file uploads in Rails 3.1, and I'm looking for a way to save server space. Many of the photos being uploaded are upwards of 20MB, so after processing them down to 1024 x 1024, I would like to remove the original. Is there any easy way to do that in the uploader class?

Thanks,
--Mark

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define an after_save callback in you model and delete the photo..

I dont know your model but something like this may work if you customize it:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :convert_file
  after_create :delete_original_file

  def convert_file
    # do the things you have to do
  end 

  def delete_original_file
    File.delete self.original_file_path if File.exists? self.original_file_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Did it work for you? If yes, would be nice if you mark my answer ask correct.

Comment: You have to ask to Mark, since his is the question owner, not me, sorry.

Answer (score 23):

I used to have two versions and realized that I did not not need the original

So instead of having

```
version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
  end

version :normal do
   process :resize_to_limit => [300,300]
end
```

I removed :normal and added this

```
process :resize_to_limit => [300, 300]
```

Now the original is saved in size I need and I don't have a third unused image on the server

Comment: awesome, i think this is a great solution to just do a process outside of any version block so that you don't save the original version at all if it's really big. thanks

Comment: I'd like to add that if you still want to include `"normal_"` in the filename of the uploaded file, as would happen in a `version` block, you can explicitly assign a version name to the base uploader using `version_names << :medium`.

Answer (score 7):

everyone!
Selected solution does not work for me.
My solution:

```
  after :store, :remove_original_file

  def remove_original_file(p)
    if self.version_name.nil?
      self.file.delete if self.file.exists?
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  after :store, :delete_original_file

  def delete_original_file(new_file)
    File.delete path if version_name.blank?
  end

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file
  .
  . # other configurations

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit hack but has performance advantage

```
my_uploader.send :store_versions!, open(my_file)
```