# Resize image to original versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, minimagick

I am using carrierwave and mini magick. In the uploader i have

```
process resize_to_fit: [300,200]
```

Now, all the uploaded images were processed, but I now i need the original version. Is there a way to write a migration and restore the image version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not. You could resize the resized images, but you will loose quality and that's probably not what you are after.

Update: after some digging, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579425/how-can-i-make-carrierwave-not-save-the-original-file-after-versions-are-process) (look at the second answer). So depending on how you save your images, you might still have the originals. In which case you can use [this technique](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#recreating-versions) to recreate your images from the original.