# How to not save original image using Fog and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, fog

I've been searching all day on how to not save the original file on Amazon S3's server.  Everytime, my code produces 3 versions of the same image.  no_version.png, thumb.png, and original.png.

I've looked on StackOverflow and I've tried using this code:

```
  after :store, :unlink_original

  def unlink_original(file)
    File.delete if version_name.blank?
  end
```

However, it still produces 3 versions.

I've also tried the variation using path:

```
  after :store, :unlink_original

  def unlink_original(file)
    File.delete path if version_name.blank?
  end
```

However, this produces the error: **No such file or directory - uploads/L4l8n.jpg**

Here is my ImageUploader.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  after :store, :unlink_original

  def unlink_original(file)
    File.delete if version_name.blank?
  end

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  # def store_dir
  #   "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  # end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url
    # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
    asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default_link.png"].compact.join('_'))

    # "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :original, :if => :is_file_upload?
  # process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200], :if => :is_not_file_upload?

  # Default version always saves thumbs
  version :thumb do 
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
    process :convert => 'png'
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

  protected
    def is_file_upload? picture
      model.remote_image_url.blank?
    end

    # def is_not_file_upload? picture
    #   not model.remote_image_url.blank?
    # end
end
```

Comment: Maybe related to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579425/how-can-i-make-carrierwave-not-save-the-original-file-after-versions-are-process

Comment: @Arkan hey I tried the suggested solution, and I just get the error undefined method `to_file' for #<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x00000004f24870>

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution

```
after :store, :remove_original_file

  def remove_original_file(p)
    if self.version_name.nil?
      self.file.delete if self.file.exists?
    end
  end
```

This will remove the image from aws

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you are after. Is the scenario: user will upload image A, you will process image A into version B and C, and want to discard image A and keep version B and C? If so, try something like

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  process :set_content_type
  process :resize_to_limit => [1000, 1000]
  process :convert => 'png'

  version :C do 
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
    process :convert => 'png'
  end
```

In this case, you will have two versions of the original uploaded image stored: the first one is 1000xwhatever, and the second is 200xwhatever. The original image is not saved. The first version can be accessed directly from .remote_image while the second can be accessed from .remote_image.C. Make sense?

Comment: This makes sense, but it's not exactly what I'm after.  I was wondering if there was a way just to keep version C.

Comment: just put the process statements at the top level of the uploader then (not nested in a version). For example, if you have an uploader with no versions and these to processes `process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]` and `process :convert => 'png'`, you won't save the original, just a copy that fits within a 200x200 square.