# Process only original file with carrier wave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm uploading an image using carrierwave while also creating a thumbnail version. I'm also trying to apply a watermark to the original file only (not the thumbnail).

This is what I'm trying:

````
  process :watermark

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [80, 50]
    process :quality => 60
  end

  protected

  def watermark
    if self.version_name.nil?
      < apply watermark here >
    end
  end
end```

The watermark is applied to all versions, including the thumbnail. Is ether a way to achieve this without creating another version named :original ?

Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [CarrierWave documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#adding-versions):

> One important thing to remember is that `process` is called before versions are created. This can cut down on processing cost.

In your case, the watermark is applied and then the thumbnail is generated.

I think that the best solution would be to:

1. create additional version (`:original`)
2. delete the original file that was uploaded and keep only the `thumb` and `original` versions of the file ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579425/how-can-i-make-carrierwave-not-save-the-original-file-after-versions-are-process))

Comment: I missed that part of the docs. I think you're right however, that's the best way to proceed. Thanks!